# Dependency property on custom user control

Tags: wpf

I have a big issue here.
Here's the thing:

I have a custom control which contains a RichTextBox. In this rich text box i introduce hyperlinks and textblocks.

In the user Control I have Property named Designer which returns the serialized flow document from the richtextbox contained in my usercontrol.

```
public string Designer
    {
        get
        {
            return XamlWriter.Save(linkRtb.Document);
        }
        set
        {
            var stringReader = new StringReader(value);
            var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
            linkRtb.Document = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(xmlTextReader);

            OnPropertyChanged("Designer");
        }
    }
```

Binding anything to this property works. But what i want to do is to bind this property to something that i have in code behind. The problem is that if I make Designer a dependency property the binding doesn't work and i have no clue why.

The binding that i want to do looks like this:

```
Designer="{Binding Source=CodeBehindClass, Path=CodeBehindVariable, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: What is `CodeBehindClass` in the binding? Anyway, the first thing to do when dealing with binding issues is to run your app under debugger and look in the Output window in Visual Studio to check for binding errors.

Comment: Could you provide the code you used to make Designer a dependency property?

Comment: I sort of solved this problem. From what i have read i understood that you cannot add any logic to the get and set for the dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

> From what i have read i understood that you cannot add any logic to the get and set for the dependency property.

Correct, use the [`PropertyChangedCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata.propertychangedcallback.aspx) in the metadata upon DP registration instead.